# How to write an update query that sets a value based on weather a subquery is empty or not

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables named tasks and task_groups. Each task belongs to a task_group. This is reflected by making tasks.task_group have the value of a unique task_group identifier (column keyid in task_group). I want to write a query that sets task_group.status 0 ONLY if there is ANY task in the group that has status 0. This is the query I wrote:

```
UPDATE task_groups AS tg JOIN
       tasks AS t
        ON t.task_group = tg.keyid AND
           EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM tasks AS t 
                   WHERE t.task_group = tg.keyid AND t.status = 0
                  ) 
    SET tg.status = 0;
```

However it does not match anything and hence it doesn't work. Can any one tell me what is wrong with the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `where` clause:

```
update task_groups tg set tg.status = 0 
where exists (select * from tasks where task_group = tg.keyid and status = 0);
```